# Por que no MOS 6502 o SBC subtrai 2 em vez de 1 na primeira vez?

Tags: assembly

Estou tentando aprender Assembly para o MOS 6502 e me deparei com um comportamento inusitado ao testar meu código no [emulador online](https://skilldrick.github.io/easy6502/).

Código

```
LDA #$5 ; A=5
SBC #$1 ; A=3 mas deveria ser 4
SBC #$1 ; A=2 mas deveria ser 3
SBC #$1 ; A=1 mas deveria ser 2
SBC #$1 ; A=0 mas deveria ser 1
```

Se eu adicionar um `SEC` entre a 1ª e a 2ª linha eu obtenho o resultado esperado

Por quê isso acontece?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SBC é "Subtrair com Carry".

Carry é o que chamamos de "Vai um" popularmente, numa soma (ou "empresta um" numa subtração).

Em decimal, segue um exemplo de Carry:

```
                   ₁  ← carry       ₁
      17           17               17       somando o Carry
    + 05    →    + 05       →     + 05      (o 1 que subimos) 
    ————         ————             ————     obtemos o resultado
                    2               22      correto, que é 22
```

Em binário a lógica é a mesma.

**Importante:** apesar de eu ter dado um exemplo com os dois dígitos decimais, a complexidade do carry não é por causa dos bits de um mesmo byte. O Carry é usado para passar bits de um byte para outro, por exemplo se tiver 0x00 0xff e somar um no 0xff, o byte volta pra 0x00 e o carry é setado, para posteriormente você usar no byte mais significativo, chegando em 0x01 0x00 (e assim por diante, se for usar mais que 8 bits).

Sabendo o que é o Carry, vamos ao que aconteceu no código:

- O primeiro problema é que você não sabe como o Carry estava no início da operação. Pode ser que o processador tenha anotado o "vai um" de uma operação anterior.
- O segundo é que mesmo que estivesse zerado, o Carry é meio contraintuitivo em subtração, pois funciona "invertido".

Para resolver, temos essas duas instruções:

- `CLC` é "Clear Carry"
- `SEC` é "Set Carry"

Se fosse uma adição, precisariamos de um `CLC` antes de começar. Como se trata de subtração, é o inverso, precisamos "setar" o Carry com o `SEC` antes de começar, ficando assim o código:

```
    LDA #$5 ; A=5
    SEC     ; Setamos o Carry para iniciar.
    SBC #$1 ; A=4, como esperado.
    SBC #$1 ; A=3, como esperado.
    SBC #$1 ; A=2, como esperado.
    SBC #$1 ; A=1, como esperado.
```